# PureScript by example (custom Foldable)

Tags: functional-programming, purescript

Currently I'm reading `PureScript by example` book and have question about one of exercises:

Chapter 6, exercise 5 at the end of the chapter.

```
Write a Foldable instance for NonEmpty. Hint: resuse the foldable instance for arrays.
data NonEmpty a = NonEmpty a (Array a)
```

My initial thought was to implement it like this:

```
instance foldableNonEmpty :: Foldable (Array (a)) => Foldable (NonEmpty a) where
  foldr f b (NonEmpty a ar) = NonEmpty a (foldr f b ar)
  foldl f b (NonEmpty a ar) = NonEmpty a (foldl f b ar)
  foldMap m (NonEmpty a ar) = NonEmpty a (foldMap m ar)
```

But this doesn't work and currently I can't figure out why (compiler error can't help me)

```
Could not match kind
  Type -> Type
with kind
  Type

while checking the kind of Foldable (Array a) => Foldable (NonEmpty a)
```

in value declaration foldableNonEmpty

Can someone point out in which direction should I dig to find an answer?

Comment: Take a look at how [`Foldable` is defined for `Array`](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-foldable-traversable/blob/v3.4.0/src/Data/Foldable.purs#L120). Do you see any differences from your definition?

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, previous it was not helpful for me, but with explanation from wuct I found it usefull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is saying that `Foldable` expected to receive a type constructor (`Type -> Type`), but you are giving it a concrete type (`Type`). For example: `Maybe` and `Array` are type constructors; `Maybe a` and `Array a` are concrete types. In your case, `NonEmpty a` is the concrete type. I believe now you get the idea how to fix it.

Moreover, your implementation is also wrong. The type of `foldr` is

```
foldr :: forall a b. (a -> b -> b) -> b -> f a -> b
```

You should return a value with type `b`, but you are returning a value with `f a`, which is `NonEmpty a` in your case.

I left my answer in [this link](http://try.purescript.org/?session=9bb6327d-c3c0-5607-556a-2fc41f4550d1&backend=core&gist=b8f7f693015cbe90bd758e3078295a5e) in case you still can not figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation of compiler error. Just want to confirm: first row (Type -> Type) is always what compiler want and second is what he really have?  I was able to resolve this problem, thank you for help! Need more practice...

Comment: @Alex you are right. The first row is what the compiler wants.